# Button weight in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

This the code I have

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New "
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New "
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New "
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New "
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="#ffffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New "
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="New "
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: buttons]

I want the first This's width be as the first two New and the second This's width be as the third New

So it looks like this:

[image: buttons2]

The only way I can do that is by putting the weights on 0.93/0.07

Shouldn't it work with weights 2/1 as the code above is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try leaving out `android:weightSum="3"` for your second row of buttons. When you omit weightSum, the weights of the views are totaled by default and they essentially become straight proportions (ratios like 2 to 1). So, just using weight=2 for first button (id button5), then weight=1 for second button (id button7) should work.

Also, when using `layout_weight`, make sure that your resizable views have `layout_width` or `layout_height` equal to zero.

Try this xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New "
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New "
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New "
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New "
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New "
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="New "
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I write to have the layout you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New "
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New "
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New "
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="New "
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="New "
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="6"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="New "
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the result

[image]

There is only one thing I'm not sure and is why in my last LinearLayout I had to put weight = 6 to have the button in that height. I'm looking for the reason :/

Comment: look at hungryghost's answer. The 0dp on the height and width are what make the layouts work.

Comment: I edit mi answer and the result is the same. It works like you want but for that result I had to use weight = 6 .@hungryghost was right, I had to used layouts  equal to zero but mainly for performance.  The system calculates the size of the view based on its layout width and height values when it builds the view.
Now, if you include the layout_weight attribute then the system has to calculate the width (or height) a second time, using the weight value to allocate space. It’s twice the work. This is why you should set the width or height attribute value to 0dp so there’s no extra calculation.